# Cumolocity - Send a REST to an external Webserver

Tags: rest, api, cumulocity

Is there a way to send a REST request to an external web server from Cumulocity?

My Use Case: When an event occurs, an external web server is to be notified.

I read that it should go with the development of own applications.Is there an easier way?

I would be very grateful for help or a code sample.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box feature to configure. However there are a couple of ways to achieve that.

1. If you want to trigger a call on certain specific occassions you could use the Apama streaming analytics. It allows you to trigger custom HTTP request on incoming data or even under certain conditions.
2. The available way to get notified on incoming data is long polling or websockets. So you would need a small service subscribing and then sending yor call.